# max_clients limit reached, request queued tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I am using python to send multiple HTTP requests .. > 1000 requests are fired asynchronously at the same time. But i get the error: **max_clients limit reached, request queued tornado** and after a while i am getting timeout error.

How do you solve this kind of problems, sending multiple http post requests and avoiding the timeout ?

Here is the code i am using:

```
class AjaxBatchHandler(basehandler.BaseHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        # just respond with a status, no redirect to login
        if not self.get_current_user:
            self.set_status(403)

        batch = json.loads(self.get_argument("actions").encode('utf-8'))

        client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()

        batch_requests = []
        for item in batch['actions']:
            request = utils.build_request(
                self,
                action=item['action'].replace("{API}", utils.get_api_baseurl()),
                values=item['values'])
            batch_requests.append(client.fetch(request))

        try:
            batch_responses = yield batch_requests

            batch_result = dict(results=[])
            for result in batch_responses:
                batch_result['results'].append(json.loads(result.body))

        except tornado.httpclient.HTTPError as e:
            batch_result = dict(results=[])
            batch_result['results'].append({"Status": 500,
                                        "StatusMsg": e.message,
                                        "Error": e.code
                                        })

        self.write(batch_result)
```

Answer (score 5):

Either increase the `max_clients` limit (if it is appropriate for you to be sending more traffic to the site you are hitting) or slow down your requests. For the former, do

```
AsyncHTTPClient.configure(None, max_clients=1000)
```

at the beginning of your program. For the latter, either a Semaphore or a Queue can be useful for controlling the rate at which you send requests. See https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/webspider/webspider.py

Comment: by sending a lot of asynchron calls at once, by a lot a i mean 10.000 for example, than increasing max_clients ist not solving the problem. 

But I'll have a closer look in the queues. However i solved the problem for now. I am sending each call asynchron using ajax calls, and collecting the responses, when all responses are there, i am showing the result. I noticed that it is slower process but is working without timeout.